# Can a child enter the UK with his older brother even though his brother is not the person listed to accompany him on his visa?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, standard-visitor-visas, children

My mum, little brother and I plan to travel to the UK but my 15 year old brother’s visa states that it’s only valid if accompanied by my mother. Unfortunately my mum cannot travel any longer for medical reasons. Is there any way my little brother and I, his older brother, can be allowed to enter the UK without my mum?

Comment: Is there time to get a new visa for your brother, listing you, in addition to your mother, as an accompanying adult?

Comment: @DavidRicherby I think this is a different question, and has a simpler solution. The minor in this case will be traveling with a closely related adult, just not the one named on the current visa. That question had the minor traveling alone but being met at the airport by the named adult.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I think the underlying question and answer are the same: with an accompanied minor visa, you _must_ be accompanied by the nominated adult. The only difference here is that there might be time to get a new visa instead of just cancelling the trip, but I don't see what as a significant difference. Anyone with a similar problem in the future can work out their own course of action from the knowledge that the visa isn't valid.

Answer (score 6):

If your younger brother's visa lists only your mother as an accompanying adult he will be refused entry if he arrives in the UK without her. ([Source](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/if-youre-under-18))

He will need a new visa listing you as his accompanying adult.

Comment: Or list both the mother and the brother, so either can accompany the minor.